# Where do Kusto dashboard definitions live

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

In the [ADX web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data) at https://dataexplorer.azure.com/dashboards, I can see a list of Kusto based dashboards I've created or been granted access to.

Under what resource type in https://portal.azure.com/ are these assets scoped? I've used the UI to export the report definition JSON. However, I've been unable to find either the Dashboard name or guid in [Azure Resource Graph explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview) searching in the `name` & `id` fields. Notably these same queries (with different arguments) return the ADX clusters which are the data sources for the dashboards in question.

The [`az portal dashboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/portal/dashboard) commands do not appear to include Kusto dashboards as far as I can tell.

A partial inventory appears to be available in the [`.show queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/queries) system view.

```
.show queries 
| where ClientActivityId startswith "RTD;"
| extend ClientActivityIdBag = split(ClientActivityId,';')
| extend DashboardGuid = tostring(ClientActivityIdBag[1])
| summarize 
    count(), 
    min(StartedOn), 
    max(StartedOn), 
    take_any(ClientActivityId) 
  by DashboardGuid
```

This suggests to me that there is a [ReportServer DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-database-ssrs-native-mode) analouge from which I'd be able to correlate the dashboard guid to broader dashboard metadata, but I've been unable to proceed further so far.

I want to monitor shared Kusto dashboard assets for modifications. Other than logging into the web UI and using my eyeballs, how can I do this?

Comment: As per [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/azure-data-explorer-dashboards) dashboards are available in standalone web applications.

Comment: The web UI is useful for manual review. It is less useful for automated checks. If I've missed something in the docs relevant to automation, I'd be happy to have it pointed out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADX Dashboard definitions are homed in an Azure CosmosDB instance not directly accessible to any user tenants.

The [ADX feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a952add5-eb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) has the following requests regarding API support for dashboards, but at this time no workarounds have been posted nor official support made public.

- [Shared Workspace for Dashboards](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c94b8e86-2746-ed11-a81b-000d3ae3db6e)
- [API for Exporting Dashboards](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/702efd63-4f97-ed11-a81b-000d3adb7ffd)
- [Create dashboard programmatically](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/fefdb9df-a17e-ec11-a81b-000d3a7cc2c1)
- [Provide permissions to the dashboards w/o permissions to the underlying data](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c94b8e86-2746-ed11-a81b-000d3ae3db6e)

Hopefully the recent [general availability release](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/general-availability-adx-dashboards/ba-p/3749361) implies that this support is forthcoming.